# Making Shiny UI Adjustments Without Redrawing Leaflet Maps

Tags: shiny, leaflet, shinydashboard

#### The Problem

I am creating a shinydashboard to help a client explore some spatial data. The UI design I'd like to achieve allows the user to easily switch between two layouts:

- Map Only
- Map + Data Table

I'm having trouble implementing this design because every time the user switches between layouts two problems occur:

1. The map is redrawn
2. The ActionButtons break, preventing the user from exploring the data

My guess is that is may be a namespace issue, but I don't have any experience creating [modules](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) (seems complicated and scary).

Does anyone have a good strategy for resolving these issues?

#### Reproducible Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(DT)

header <- dashboardHeader(
        title = "Example"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                    fluidPage(
                            fluidRow(
                                    column(1),
                                    column(11,
                                           checkboxInput(inputId = "show",label = "Show Data Table",value = TRUE),
                                           p(),
                                           actionButton("zoom","Zoom to Oz",icon = icon("search-plus")))
                            )
                    )

                    )

        )
)

body <-   dashboardBody(
        fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                        uiOutput("content")
                )

        )
)      

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)        

server <- function(input, output) {

        output$map <- renderLeaflet({

                pal <- colorNumeric("Set2", quakes$mag)
                leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
                        fitBounds(~min(long), ~min(lat), ~max(long), ~max(lat)) %>% 
                        addCircles(radius = ~10^mag/10, weight = 1, color = "#777777",
                                                              fillColor = ~pal(mag), fillOpacity = 0.7, popup = ~paste(mag)
                                                   )
        })

        output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
                quakes %>% select(lat,long,mag) %>% DT::datatable()
        })


        observeEvent(input$zoom,{
                leafletProxy(mapId = "map",data = quakes$mag) %>% 
                        setView(132.166667, -23.033333,  zoom = 4)
        })




        output$content <- renderUI({

                makeCol_table <- function(){
                        column(4,
                               box(title = "",width = 12,height = "100%",
                                   DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
                               )
                }

                makeCol_map8 <- function(){
                        column(8,
                               box(title = "",width = 12,height = "100%",
                                   leafletOutput("map",height = "600px"))
                               )
                }
                makeCol_map12 <- function(){
                        column(12,
                               box(title = "",width = 12,height = "100%",
                                   leafletOutput("map",height = "600px"))
                               )
                }


                fluidRow(

                        if(input$show == T)({makeCol_table()})else ({NULL}),
                        if(input$show == T)({makeCol_map8()}) else ({makeCol_map12()})

                )





        })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

#### Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.3          shinydashboard_0.5.1
[3] DT_0.1.39            RColorBrewer_1.1-2  
[5] leaflet_1.0.1.9003   shiny_0.13.1        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3        magrittr_1.5       munsell_0.4.3     
 [4] colorspace_1.2-6   xtable_1.8-2       R6_2.1.2          
 [7] plyr_1.8.3         tools_3.2.3        parallel_3.2.3    
[10] DBI_0.3.1          htmltools_0.3      lazyeval_0.1.10   
[13] yaml_2.1.13        digest_0.6.9       assertthat_0.1    
[16] htmlwidgets_0.6    rsconnect_0.4.1.11 mime_0.4          
[19] scales_0.4.0       jsonlite_0.9.19    httpuv_1.3.3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The ActionButtons break" - how does it break. When I run your code the action button always works?

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. When I run my code the ActionButton ("Zoom to Oz") stops functioning after the check box has been clicked.

Answer (score 3):

I've re-written your app so that it uses @daattali 's brilliant [`shinyjs`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyjs/index.html) package. I've also removed some of the formatting just to shorten it.

Ultimately we can make use of `javascript` `hide` and `show` methods to hide your box that contains your table.

Note also that I've moved your map and table to the `ui`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Example"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
              checkboxInput(inputId = "show",label = "Show Data Table",value = TRUE),
              p(),
              actionButton("zoom","Zoom to Oz", icon = icon("search-plus")
                           )
              )
  )

body <- dashboardBody(

  ## Initialise shinyjs
  useShinyjs(),

  div(id = "box_table-outer",
    box(id = "box_table",
      title = "",
      width = 12,
      height = "100%",
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
      )
    ),
  box(title = "",
      width = 12,
      height = "100%",
      leafletOutput("map",
                    height = "600px")
      )
  )

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)        

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    pal <- colorNumeric("Set2", quakes$mag)

    leaflet(quakes) %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(~min(long), ~min(lat), ~max(long), ~max(lat)) %>% 
      addCircles(radius = ~10^mag/10, weight = 1, color = "#777777",
                 fillColor = ~pal(mag), fillOpacity = 0.7, popup = ~paste(mag)
      )
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    quakes %>% 
      select(lat,long,mag) %>% 
      DT::datatable()
  })


  observeEvent(input$zoom, {

    leafletProxy(mapId = "map",data = quakes$mag) %>% 
      setView(132.166667, -23.033333,  zoom = 4)

  })

  ## use shinyjs functions to show/hide the table box 
  ## dependant on the check-box
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    if(input$show){
      show(id = "box_table-outer")
    }else{
      hide(id = "box_table-outer")
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach, but I'm not sure I could implement my UI design with it (i.e., two columns side-by-side). Can you think of a way to set up the UI so these elements are displayed in two columns and when the table is hidden the map column expands to fill the space?

Comment: @Tiernan ah, good question. At the moment I'mn not sure I have a solution