# Changing Leaflet map according to input without redrawing (multiple polygons)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, polygons

cannot fix my problem for MULTIPLE filters/polygons. 
Currently my code works, but very slow,  I do not use **observe(), reactive(), and LeafletProxy()**, because I stumbled.

I obviously checked this answer [Changing Leaflet map according to input without redrawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433569/changing-leaflet-map-according-to-input-without-redrawing) 
and this one [Making Shiny UI Adjustments Without Redrawing Leaflet Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808776/making-shiny-ui-adjustments-without-redrawing-leaflet-maps)
 and leaflet tutorial [Using Leaflet with Shiny](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html)

In my case I have four filters and do not quite understand how to combine them together and make the map fast.

My sample data:

```
Country Client  Channel Status
Country 1   Client 1    Agent network   Launched
Country 2   Client 2    Debit cards Launched
Country 3   Client 3    M-banking   Planning
Country 4   Client 4    M-banking   Launched
Country 5   Client 5    Agent network   Launched
Country 6   Client 6    Agent network   Launched
Country 7   Client 7    Agent network   Pilot
```

**This code works**

```
# Packages
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

# Set working directory
setwd("C: /My Shiny apps")

# Read csv, which was created specifically for this app
projects <- read.csv("sample data10.csv", header = TRUE) 

# Read a shapefile
countries <- readOGR(".","ne_50m_admin_0_countries")

# Merge data
projects.df <- merge(countries, projects, by.x = "name", by.y = "Country")
class(projects.df)


# Shiny code

# UI

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
            titlePanel("Map sample)"), 
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                selectInput("countryInput", "Country",
                            choices = c("Choose country", "Country 1",
                                        "Country 2",
                                        "Country 3",
                                        "Country 4",
                                        "Country 5",
                                        "Country 6", 
                                        "Country 7"),
                            selected = "Choose country"),
                selectInput("clientInput", " Client",
                            choices = c("Choose Client", "Client 1",
                                        "Client 2",
                                        "Client 3",
                                        "Client 4",
                                        "Client 5",
                                        "Client 6"),
                            selected = "Choose Client"),
                selectInput("channeInput", "Channel",
                            choices = c("Choose Channel", "Agent network", 
"M-banking", "Debit cards"),
                            selected = "Choose Channel"),
                selectInput("statusInput", "Status",
                            choices = c("Choose status", "Launched", 
"Pilot", "Planning"),
                            selected = "Choose status")
              ),

              mainPanel(leafletOutput(outputId = 'map', height = 800) 
              )
            )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$map <- renderLeaflet({

pal1 <- colorFactor(
  palette = "Red",
  domain = input$countryInput)

pal2 <- colorFactor(
  palette = "Yellow",
  domain = input$clientInput)

pal3 <- colorFactor(
  palette = "Green",
  domain = input$channelInput)

pal4 <- colorFactor(
  palette = "Blue",
  domain = input$statusInput)

# Create a pop-up
state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$name, 
                      "<br><strong> Client: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$ Client,
                      "<br><strong> Channel: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Channel
                      "<br><strong>Status: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Status)

# Create a map

projects.map <- projects.df %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles("Stamen.Watercolor") %>% 
  setView(11.0670977,0.912484, zoom = 4) %>% 
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal1(projects.df$name), 
              popup = state_popup,
              color = "#BDBDC3",
              fillOpacity = 1,
              weight = 1) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal2(projects.df$Client), 
              popup = state_popup,
              color = "#BDBDC3",
              opacity = 1,
              weight = 1) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal3(projects.df$Channel), 
              popup = state_popup,
              color = "#BDBDC3",
              opacity = 1,
              weight = 1) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal4(projects.df$Status), 
              popup = state_popup,
              color = "#BDBDC3",
              opacity = 1,
              weight = 1)
})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please help me to fix it with **observe, reactive, and LeafletProxy** and without redrawing map every time.

For me having these **multiple filters/polygons** make the situation really difficult.

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you send me the necessary csv and shape files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this is in line with what you are trying to achieve. I prefer have separate global, ui and server files. My sample project file is:

"","Country","Client","Channel","Status"
"1","Croatia","Client 1","Agent network","Launched"
"2","Germany","Client 2","Debit cards","Launched"
"3","Italy","Client 3","M-banking","Planning"
"4","France","Client 4","M-banking","Launched"
"5","Slovenia","Client 5","Agent network","Launched"
"6","Austria","Client 6","Agent network","Launched"
"7","Hungary","Client 7","Agent network","Pilot"

global.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinythemes)
    library(leaflet)
    library(rgdal)

    # Set working directory

    # Read csv, which was created specifically for this app
    projects <- read.csv("sample data10.csv", header = TRUE) 

    # Read a shapefile
    countries <- readOGR(".","ne_50m_admin_0_countries")

    # Merge data
    projects.df <- merge(countries, projects, by.x = "name", by.y = "Country")
```

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinythemes)
    library(leaflet)
    library(rgdal)

    shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                      titlePanel("Map sample"), 
                      sidebarLayout(
                              sidebarPanel(
                                      selectInput("countryInput", "Country",
                                                  choices = c("Choose country", "Croatia",
                                                              "Germany",
                                                              "Italy",
                                                              "France",
                                                              "Slovenia",
                                                              "Austria", 
                                                              "Hungary"),
                                                  selected = "Choose country"),
                                      selectInput("clientInput", " Client",
                                                  choices = c("Choose Client", "Client 1",
                                                              "Client 2",
                                                              "Client 3",
                                                              "Client 4",
                                                              "Client 5",
                                                              "Client 6"),
                                                  selected = "Choose Client"),
                                      selectInput("channeInput", "Channel",
                                                  choices = c("Choose Channel", "Agent network", 
                                                              "M-banking", "Debit cards"),
                                                  selected = "Choose Channel"),
                                      selectInput("statusInput", "Status",
                                                  choices = c("Choose status", "Launched", 
                                                              "Pilot", "Planning"),
                                                  selected = "Choose status")
                              ),

                              mainPanel(leafletOutput(outputId = 'map', height = 800) 
                              )
                      )
    ))
```

server.R

```
  shinyServer(function(input, output) {
            output$map <- renderLeaflet({
                    leaflet(projects.df) %>% 
                            addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Watercolor) %>% 
                            setView(11.0670977,0.912484, zoom = 4) #%>% 

            })
            # observers
            # selected country
            selectedCountry <- reactive({
                   projects.df[projects.df$name == input$countryInput, ] 
            })
            observe({
                    state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>", 
                                          selectedCountry()$name, 
                                          "<br><strong> Client: </strong>", 
                                          selectedCountry()$Client,
                                          "<br><strong> Channel: </strong>", 
                                          selectedCountry()$Channel,
                                          "<br><strong>Status: </strong>", 
                                          selectedCountry()$Status)

                    leafletProxy("map", data = selectedCountry()) %>%
                            clearShapes() %>%
                            addPolygons(fillColor =  "red",
                                        popup = state_popup,
                                        color = "#BDBDC3",
                                        fillOpacity = 1,
                                        weight = 1)
            })
            # selected clients
            selectedClient <- reactive({
                    tmp <- projects.df[!is.na(projects.df$Client), ] 
                    tmp[tmp$Client == input$clientInput, ]
            })
            observe({
                    state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>",
                                          selectedClient()$name,
                                          "<br><strong> Client: </strong>",
                                          selectedClient()$Client,
                                          "<br><strong> Channel: </strong>",
                                          selectedClient()$Channel,
                                          "<br><strong>Status: </strong>",
                                          selectedClient()$Status)

                    leafletProxy("map", data = selectedClient()) %>%
                            clearShapes() %>%
                            addPolygons(fillColor =  "yellow",
                                        popup = state_popup,
                                        color = "#BDBDC3",
                                        fillOpacity = 1,
                                        weight = 1)
            })
            # selected channel
            selectedChannel <- reactive({
                    tmp <- projects.df[!is.na(projects.df$Channel), ] 
                    tmp[tmp$Channel == input$channeInput, ]
            })
            observe({
                    state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>",
                                          selectedChannel()$name,
                                          "<br><strong> Client: </strong>",
                                          selectedChannel()$Client,
                                          "<br><strong> Channel: </strong>",
                                          selectedChannel()$Channel,
                                          "<br><strong>Status: </strong>",
                                          selectedChannel()$Status)

                    leafletProxy("map", data = selectedChannel()) %>%
                            clearShapes() %>%
                            addPolygons(fillColor =  "green",
                                        popup = state_popup,
                                        color = "#BDBDC3",
                                        fillOpacity = 1,
                                        weight = 1)
            })
            # selected status
            selectedStatus <- reactive({
                    tmp <- projects.df[!is.na(projects.df$Status), ] 
                    tmp[tmp$Status == input$statusInput, ]
            })
            observe({
                    state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>",
                                          selectedStatus()$name,
                                          "<br><strong> Client: </strong>",
                                          selectedStatus()$Client,
                                          "<br><strong> Channel: </strong>",
                                          selectedStatus()$Channel,
                                          "<br><strong>Status: </strong>",
                                          selectedStatus()$Status)

                    leafletProxy("map", data = selectedStatus()) %>%
                            clearShapes() %>%
                            addPolygons(fillColor =  "blue",
                                        popup = state_popup,
                                        color = "#BDBDC3",
                                        fillOpacity = 1,
                                        weight = 1)
            })        
    })
```

Let me know...

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple things you can do to set up your code, and a few things that need to be cleaned up.

First, make sure your `output$map` variable is your minimum viable map -- it should load the basemap, set the lat/lon, set the zoom, and that's about it. So it might look like:

```
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet('map') %>%
  addTiles("Stamen.Watercolor") %>% 
  setView(11.0670977,0.912484, zoom = 4)
})
```

Then you can create a different output for each of your polygons using `renderPlot` and wrap it in a conditional statement:

```
output$country_one <- renderPlot({
if("Country 1" %in% input$"countryInput") {
 leafletProxy('map') %>%
 addPolygons(data = projects.df, fillColor = ~pal1(projects.df$name), 
              popup = paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$name, 
                      "<br><strong> Client: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$ Client,
                      "<br><strong> Channel: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Channel
                      "<br><strong>Status: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Status),
              color = "#BDBDC3",
              fillOpacity = 1,
              weight = 1)
}
)}
```

Then in your UI section, you call each output one after another:

```
leafletProxy('map')
plotOutput('country_one')
```

After cleaning up your palettes (domain must be numeric), your code might look like this:

```
# Packages
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

# Set working directory
setwd("C: /My Shiny apps")

# Read csv, which was created specifically for this app
projects <- read.csv("sample data10.csv", header = TRUE) 

# Read a shapefile
countries <- readOGR(".","ne_50m_admin_0_countries")

# Merge data
projects.df <- merge(countries, projects, by.x = "name", by.y = "Country")
class(projects.df)

# Shiny code

# UI

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
            titlePanel("Map sample"), 
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                selectInput("countryInput", "Country",
                            choices = c("Choose country", "Country 1","Country 2","Country 3","Country 4","Country 5","Country 6", "Country 7"),
                            selected = "Choose country"),
                selectInput("clientInput", " Client",
                            choices = c("Choose Client", "Client 1","Client 2","Client 3","Client 4","Client 5","Client 6"),
                            selected = "Choose Client"),
                selectInput("channeInput", "Channel",
                            choices = c("Choose Channel", "Agent network", "M-banking", "Debit cards"),
                            selected = "Choose Channel"),
                selectInput("statusInput", "Status",
                            choices = c("Choose status", "Launched", "Pilot", "Planning"),
                            selected = "Choose status")
              ),

              mainPanel(
                leafletOutput('map'), 
                plotOutput('country_output'),
                plotOutput('client_output'),
                plotOutput('channel_output'),
                plotOutput('status_output')
              )
            )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

pal1 <- colorFactor(palette = "Blues", domain = c(0, 100))
pal2 <- colorFactor(palette = "Blues", domain = c(0, 100))
pal3 <- colorFactor(palette = "Blues", domain = c(0, 100))
pal4 <- colorFactor(palette = "Blues", domain = c(0, 100))

output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet('map') %>%
      addTiles("Stamen.Watercolor") %>% 
      setView(11.0670977,0.912484, zoom = 4)
})

output$country_output <- renderPlot({
  if("Country 1" %in% input$"countryInput") { # sample conditional statement
    leafletProxy('map') %>% # initalize the map
      clearGroup("polys") %>% # clear any previous polygons
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal1(projects.df$name), 
                  popup = paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>",projects.df$name,"<br><strong> Client: </strong>",projects.df$ Client,"<br><strong> Channel: </strong>",projects.df$Channel,"<br><strong>Status: </strong>", projects.df$Status), 
                  color = "#BDBDC3", fillOpacity = 1, weight = 1, group = "polys")
  }
})

output$client_output <- renderPlot({
  leafletProxy('map') %>% # initalize the map
    clearGroup("polys") %>% # clear any previous polygons
    addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal2(projects.df$Client), 
                popup = paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>",projects.df$name,"<br><strong> Client: </strong>",projects.df$ Client,"<br><strong> Channel: </strong>",projects.df$Channel,"<br><strong>Status: </strong>", projects.df$Status), 
                color = "#BDBDC3", fillOpacity = 1, weight = 1, group = "polys")
})  

output$channel_output <- renderPlot({
  leafletProxy('map') %>% # initalize the map
    clearGroup("polys") %>% # clear any previous polygons
    addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal3(projects.df$Channel), 
                popup = paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>",projects.df$name,"<br><strong> Client: </strong>",projects.df$ Client,"<br><strong> Channel: </strong>",projects.df$Channel,"<br><strong>Status: </strong>", projects.df$Status), 
                color = "#BDBDC3", fillOpacity = 1, weight = 1, group = "polys")
})    

output$status_output <- renderPlot({
  leafletProxy('map') %>% # initalize the map
    clearGroup("polys") %>% # clear any previous polygons
    addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal4(projects.df$Status), 
                popup = paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>",projects.df$name,"<br><strong> Client: </strong>",projects.df$ Client,"<br><strong> Channel: </strong>",projects.df$Channel,"<br><strong>Status: </strong>", projects.df$Status), 
                color = "#BDBDC3", fillOpacity = 1, weight = 1, group = "polys")
})      

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I can't test this because I don't have your geospatial data. So if you are encountering errors, it might be worth checking this code as well as your data source.

Comment: thanks so much. A couple more questions. 1) If I have about 30 polygons, should I repeat the same thing all 30 times for each country, client etc? 2) Palette disturbs me, because it requires to specify the domain! And I put domain for a specific input. Can I apply it for all inputs together? 3) How UI should look like with you updates? Confused. Sorry, I am brand new, my first app. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated the answer with the full code. Please forgive any potential typos. I can't test it because I don't have your geospatial file, so if you encounter errors, please check your data source as well as this code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time. However, still does not work. Map is dead, gray shadow on territory + even filters do not work now.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/496#issuecomment-650122985) you can also create the map once and then recolor the polygons as you like.

This involves some javascript code, including the `leafletjs` code and then using the `setShapeStyle` function. Note that both the javascript and the setShapeStyle function are shown in the issue above.

```
# in ui
ui <- fluidPage(leafletjs, ...)

# in server
observe({
  leafletProxy("map") %>%
    setShapeStyle(layerId = ~LayerIDs, fillColor=input$color)
})
```